# Get total answers count for a specified: Tag, Userid and Date-range?

Tags: support, api, users, answers

I would like to get the total number of answers provided by userid `1068142` between 
`01/07/2015-31/07/2015` with tag = `paypal`.

I have looked into [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/6515/how-to-calculate-users-who-have-posted-question-answer-using-specific-tag) but it does not help!

I have been trying this for quite sometime with no correct output.

PS: I am building a web application and can use only API calls. (So [no SEDE (yet)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6564/please-provide-a-way-to-download-sede-data-via-an-api).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stated problem is considerably easier than the question you linked.
You can **use [the `/users/{ids}/answers` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users)** to get what you want -- with a little work.
The trick is to **use a filter that returns [the `answers.tags` property](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).**

In your case, ***if you really just want totals***, and ***for one user at a time***, you can use the filter: `!GeF-5u(cSumXA` .

The general procedure is:

1. Call `/users/{ids}/answers` with the desired user ID's, the desired date ranges, and an appropriate filter.
   For example:
   [/users/1068142/answers?fromdate=1435708800&todate=1438387200&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!GeF-5u(cSumXA](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#fromdate=2015-07-01&todate=2015-08-01&order=desc&sort=creation&ids=1068142&filter=!GeF-5u%28cSumXA&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
2. This returns results like:

   ```
   {
     "items": [ {
         "tags": [
           "paypal"
         ]
       },
       ... ...
       {
         "tags": [
           "paypal-adaptive-payments"
         ]
       }
     ],
     "has_more": false,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "quota_remaining": 9984
   }
   ```
3. Use [paging](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), if necessary, to fetch all of the results.
4. Now loop through the `items` array and count how many times the `tags` array contains `"paypal"`.  (In this case 7)
5. That's your answer.

---

IMPORTANT:

1. When searching for date ranges, [you almost always want to increment the `todate` by one full day](https://stackapps.com/a/6172/7653) (see the link for details).
   For example, if you want items from 12-12-2012 to 12-13-2012, you would use `todate=1355443200` (The equivalent of 12 AM on 12-14-2012).
2. If you want more information per answer, or you search for more than 1 user ID at a time, then you will have to [edit your own custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/6560/7653).  It is best if you use a filter that only returns the items you need (plus all of the `.wrapper` handshaking).